# Published Excel macro fails to be recognized

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I downloaded [this macro](http://www.atlaspm.com/toms-tutorials-for-excel/toms-tutorials-for-excel-name-your-sheet-tab-same-as-cell-value/) to apply names to worksheets (worth noting that this page is also referenced in Microsoft's help pages somewhere).  But when I try to run the macro, it's like it doesn't exist.  If I select Macros from the Developer tab, it's not there (and yes, I've checked "all open workbooks").  If I open the VB editor window and open the module, I can see the code, but selecting Run or Debug 
<kbd>F8</kbd> does nothing at all.  No error, no highlighted code.  All works as expected for all my other macros.
This is Excel2010 on Windows7Enterprise.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not run this macro. It goes into the Worksheet_Change event which is the specific Worksheet object module (ie. Sheet1 object module, Sheet2 object module, etc).

It is an event that fires *automatically* when you modify a cell in worksheet.

There instructions how to *run* this are actually on that web so it's worth reading them! :)

This is where the code should be placed

[image]

You can read more about the `Worksheet_Change()` event [**here**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839775.aspx)

---

Just in case you still wander how to *run* this

place the code in the Sheet1 object module code area

go back to your spreadsheet Sheet1

type in a name in cell A1, and your sheet1 name will immediately change to whatever you've typed as long as it doesn't cause macro to exit at some point. The restrictions are mentioned [here](http://www.atlaspm.com/toms-tutorials-for-excel/toms-tutorials-for-excel-name-your-sheet-tab-same-as-cell-value/)

Comment: Aha ;-).  Thanks so much.  I knew it was to be placed in the worksheet codespace, but didn't understand about the "autofire"